# Cache CoreData store in memory

Tags: cocoa, caching, core-data

I have a CoreData store contain two types of entities - `Foo` and `Bar` backed by a SQLite store. `Foo` can be expected to have relatively few instances (~1000), all of which are extremely frequently accessed and traversed. `Bar` on the other hand can go into the millions, and each instance of `Bar` is relatively infrequently accessed.

My question is, does CoreData already optimize for this type of asymmetric access by default? If not, is there any way to tell coreData to always cache all the instances of `Foo` in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two context and all the trouble that results. What you can do, is to fetch all `Foo` objects into memory with an `NSFetchRequest` and that'll give you what you want.

Make sure the fetch request has `includesPropertyValues` set to `YES` (default) to have all the data pulled in.

Comment: The original question stated that he had several millions of Bar instances. Having 2 separate MOC would allow him to periodically reset the `Bar` MOC so these objects don't take up memory for no reason. It **is** a bit more work but it's definitely the way to go imo.

Comment: That's true. Cross-store relationships are really hard to manage, though.

Comment: Afaik he didn't mention anything about the 2 entities being related. Either way, I was taking about having 2 object **contexts**, not stores. You would have to use the objectIDs to pass the objects between MOCs but it's not as bad as having multiple stores.

Answer (score 1):

Instances will be cached into memory only once you access them. Forcing CoreData to cache ALL of your `Foo` instances might not be such a good idea, depending on how much memory that ends up being. CoreData is pretty smart at managing memory by itself.

That being said, what you could do is have 2 separate `NSManagedObjectContexts`, one for `Foo` and the other for `Bar`. You could pre-fetch all of the Foo instances right when you're initializing that MOC and they would be retained by the MOC until you call `reset` on it (which you might want to do more often on the `Bar` MOC).